# How to copy/burn a loop device image to a partition?

Tags: linux, loop-device, disk-image

I'm building a rootfs for a embedded device.

I start by making an empty loopback file system, then mount it, and add files to it.

When I finish, I end up with a file system image. Then I can burn the image to actual media to be used by the device.

**Question: How do I write this image to actual media, say a partition of an mmc card at `/dev/sdX1`?**

What I'm doing now is to `dd` or `cat` from image file to `/dev/sdX1`. But I'm wondering what happens when image file and target partition are not of the same size?

Shall I pad the image file to be larger than the partition, or make it just enough to hold the data and smaller than the target?

This is different from doing disk to disk copy, like `/dev/sda` to `disk.img` then to `/dev/sdb`, where partition tables are copied and all partitions of the source and target are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the partition table on a whole disk records where the partitions end relative to the disk, the filesystem itself knows where it ends relative to the beginning of its partition.

It does not matter if there is garbage on a partition after the filesystem, apart from the wasted space on the medium. As long as your image is smaller than (or exactly as big as) the target partition, you are good.

Some filesystems can be resized to fill all available space on the partition they reside on. (Oftentimes it is more convenient to copy a slightly smaller image to a partition and than resize instead of possibly making an error when calculating exact sizes.)

Comment: I tried `cat`ing a small image file to a larger partition, the outcome is exactly as described above: partition size stays the same but total file system space(used+free) shrinks to the size of the image. Thanks!