# How to increase the size of a vfat file system to exactly the size of the containing partition?

Tags: filesystems, vfat

This is a further question after [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227308/how-to-copy-burn-a-loop-device-image-to-a-partition/227326#227326).

I google for it, but most of the search results are about how to grow the partition and the file system at the same time.

I think this question is simpler than that, because I the partition is already larger than the file system, but I want to grow the file system to fill the partition.

The reason why my file system is smaller than the partition is that I didn't format the partition by doing `mkfs` on it, but rather `cat`ing a file system image into it. And the image is smaller than the target partition.

The reason why I have to grow the file system to fully fill the partition is that my embedded SoC won't boot when there's a gap, [explained at the end of this wiki](http://elinux.org/Panda_How_to_MLO_%26_u-boot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this while upgrading the size of the microSD card in my phone.  I had used `dd` to clone the existing card onto a new card.  The new partition was larger, but the filesystem was still the same size as the previous microSD.  To solve it I used `fdisk` and `fatresize`.  Also, I should mention that I was working with the `/dev/mmcblk0p1` partition, which `fatresize` did not like for some reason (I was getting Error: `Could not stat device /dev/mmcblk0p - No such file or directory.`), so I did have to use a workaround mentioned at https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=810735 and add a soft link `sudo ln -s /dev/mmcblk0p1 /dev/tmp`.

Anyway, to resize the vfat partition (substituting `/dev/tmp` for your specific partition):

1. Use `sudo fdisk -s /dev/tmp` to determine the size of the partition in kB.  In my case this was `244244480`
2. `sudo fatresize -s 244244480k /dev/tmp` (substituting the partition size from step 1.)

As always, make sure to have a backup of the partition before attempting this!

Make sure to remove the temporary device soft link if you had to use the workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know is to shrink / grow the partition a little with `gparted` (or an old version of `parted` that still did this). Somehow the code for resizing `vfat` is hidden away in this partitioning program (or `libparted` for that matter) and there don't seem to be tools like `resize2fs` that do this directly or offer more options.

Whether such a resize is sufficient for your embedded SoC - I'm not sure how well is vfat able to adapt to arbitrary partition sizes - you linked to a program you can test with. You might have to make your partition slightly smaller so the values match.